# ASIHTTPREQUEST change view Controller on requestFinished

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, asihttprequest

I'm in a trouble with ASIHTTPRequest.

First of all in my AppDelegate I have a TabBarController. Before set my tabbarcontroller to the rootviewcontroller (self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;)
I push another view (self.window.rootViewController = getDataLaunchViewController;) which is in charge of download all the data. 
Inside this view controller(getDataLaunchViewController) I'm doing a couple of startAsynchronous request. 
Everything is alright, I get the response but when the last request is done, I'm trying to do this (inside the requestFinished):

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;

appDelegate.window.rootViewController = appDelegate.tabBarController;
```

and the App crash with EXC_BAD_ACCESS

I've done a research and I'm not too much sure what am I doing wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are working in the same thread.
I suggest you doning a "manual trick".
Build a method with your code:

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
appDelegate.window.rootViewController = appDelegate.tabBarController;
```

After, when you receive the last request, call this method like this:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(yourMethod) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
```

I hope it will help you!!

Comment: GREAT SOLUTION!!!!!! It's working properly!! 
Thank you very much  @MurdockPNR  and many thanks again for your time!! I love MIMO!!!